# How to bind data when using Dependency Properties

Tags: wpf, binding, dependency-properties, datacontext

I have a main view which contains a wrap panel, this wrappanel contains a list of usercontrols.

I get data into the usercontrol by using DependencyProperty, issue is how do i then bind in the wpf to variables in the usercontrol? if i use

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

it seems to stop the DependencyProperty from working

Comment: post relevant XAML please

Answer (score 0):

Give your control a name i.e.:

```
<UserControl x:Class="YourApp.YourNamespace"
    ... etc ...
    x:Name="_this">
```

Then all of its child controls can bind to its dependency properties like this:

```
<TextBlock Text={Binding ElementName=_this, Path=YourDependencyPropertyName}" />
```